# How to convert a pip package into a standalone py file(or files)?

Tags: python, pip

Just like the famous BeautifulSoup package, I am wondering whether there is a standard way to 
convert the package into a standalone py file or files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. It will download the package as an archive into a directory:

```
mkdir BeautifulSoup
pip install BeautifulSoup -d BeautifulSoup/
```

Or simply:

```
sudo pip install -t . BeautifulSoup
```

Will download and install Beautiful soup in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a standard way / some module to do it , but you can pretty much do it by first installing the package using pip and then you can find the .py file/files at lib/python2.7/site-packages location.

Comment: Yes, I've considered your way and `virtualenv` may also be helpful.

Comment: yes, we should always consider using virtualenv no matter what. That's correct way to have an independent separate env with python packages.

Answer (score 0):

A Python package, as long as it doesn't use compiled extensions, is basically a set of files in a directory structure, so just download the source package, find the directory which contains the python scripts, and put it where you want.

What the "build" / "install" things do (in the case of pure Python packages) is only to put the Python scripts somewhere on your Python path.